# django - List post in proximity of user

Tags: django, geolocation

I want to create a list view that will order post based on proximity of the users zip code. Is there a package or api for this? I'm getting the zip codes (for the post and user) but I don't where to go from here. Are there any tuts for this?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://realpython.com/location-based-app-with-geodjango-tutorial/) is what i was looking for (: